# Get magento category tree as an assoc array for specific store

Tags: php, magento

In my magento, I have the following category tree structure like this (note: only a few categories has been expanded):

[image]

I would like to generate an array that looks like this:

```
$categories = [
    'Default Category' => [
        'HAIR' => [
            'Hair Colouring' => [
                'Permanent Hair Colour',
                // ...etc
            ],
            'Styling' => [
                'Gel / Wax / Paste / Po',
                // ...etc
            ]
        ],
        // ... etc
    ]
];
```

Is this possible?

When researched this issue, I found that there is a magento soap api method that might return what I am after:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogCategory/catalog_category.tree.html

Is it possible to use this soap api method in an external php script useing `app/Mage.php` (without using a soap api client)?

I have tried using this method http://magentotutorial.in/how-to-create-categories-tree-structure-in-magento-programmatically/ as my starting point, but all I am getting back is `<ul></ul>`

Answer (score 0):

```
public function megamenu(){

        $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories(2);
        if(count($children) > 0){
            $i=0;
            foreach ($children as $category) {
                //echo $category->getName();
                if($category->getName()){
                $id = $category->getId();
                $data[$i]['id'] = $category->getId();
                $data[$i]['name'] = $category->getName();
                //$data[$i]['subcategory'] = array();
                $data[$i]['subcategory'] = $this->mycategory($id);
                $i++;
                }
            }
        }
        //echo "<pre>";print_r($data);
        return $data;
    }
    public function mycategory($id){
        $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($id);
        if(count($children) > 0){
            $i=0;
            foreach ($children as $category) {
                //echo $category->getName();
                $id = $category->getId();
                $sub[$i]['id'] = $category->getId();
                $sub[$i]['name'] = $category->getName();
                $sub[$i]['subcategory'] = $this->mycategory($id);
                $i++;
            }
        }
        return $sub;

    }
```